# How to find a confidence bound?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I need help to how to find $a_\alpha(\bar{X}), b_\alpha(\bar{X})$. I don't know how to find infimum and supremum which satisfies in both cases. I would appreciate any help or hint.

Let $\wp$ be a family of probability distribution on $[0,1]$, and for $P \in \wp$ let $\mu(P) := \int xP(dx)$.

Further, let

$$\wp(\mu) := \left \{P \in \wp : \mu(P)=\mu \right \}$$

for any $\mu$ in the set $\left \{ \mu(P) : P \in \wp \right \} \subset [0,1].$

$X_1, X_2, ...$ independent random variables with distribution $P=(1-\mu)\delta_0+\mu \delta_1$.

$$a_\alpha(\bar{X}):=\inf \left \{ \mu \leq \bar{X}: H^{*}(\bar{X},\mu) < -\log(\alpha)/n \right \} $$

$$b_\alpha(\bar{X}):=\sup\left \{ \mu \geq \bar{X}: H^{*}(\bar{X},\mu) < -\log(\alpha)/n \right \} $$
where $H^{*}(r,\mu)=r\log(\frac{r}{\mu})+(1-r)r\log(\frac{1-r}{1-\mu})$

Comment: What is $\bar X$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen $\bar{X}=n^{-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, I just edited and if you need more information let me know.